# Count nr of duplicate records in row in datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I want to determine the amount of duplicate records per row for certain columns in a big data table. Simple example with desired output:

```
test <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,6),c=c(5,6,9),duplicatercds=c(1,0,0))
```

Is there a command for this?

Comment: do you have sample input data for the test output?

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, it is actually just the columns a, b and c which are needed for the output. The duplicate records should be shown per row, i.e. as in duplicatercds.

Comment: maybe `mydat[, .(duplicatercds=.N - 1), by=.(a,b,c)]` ?

Comment: @chinsoon12 that is only correct for the sample data shown. the first row contains two times "1", so there is one duplicate. For the other rows there is no duplicate values, so the result is zero. I need a more general solution.

Comment: ah okok i misunderstand your qn earlier

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that the values are all numeric? If not, then your example is inadequate for testing.

Comment: @42- yes all values are numeric

Comment: OK, and suppose a row looks like: c(1,1, 0,0, 33,33,33, 99). What is the correct result?

Comment: It would be 1 + 1 + 2 = 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can melt into a long format before calculating the dupes

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,6),c=c(5,6,9))

stat <- melt(DT[, rn:=.I], id.vars="rn")[, 
    .(duplicatercds=.N - uniqueN(value)), by=.(rn)]
DT[stat, duplicatercds := duplicatercds, on=.(rn)]
```

Be careful when doing uniqueN on double values because of machine precision

There is a github fr for this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1063

---

EDIT:
Another cleaner method

```
DT[, duplicatercds := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) length(x) - uniqueN(x))]
```

---

EDIT: Added some timings:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
ncols <- 10L
nrows <- 1e4L
uniqVal <- seq_len(1000L)
test <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(uniqVal, nrows*ncols, replace=TRUE), nrow=nrows))
test[, duplicatercds := NA_real_]

f1 <- function() test[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x) { y <- table(x); sum(y) - length(y) }) ]
f2 <- function() test[, sum(table(unlist(.SD)) > 1), by=.(1:nrows)]$V1
f3 <- function() test[, apply(test, 1, function(x) sum(diff(sort(x))==0))]
f4 <- function() test[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x) length(x) - uniqueN(x))]
f5 <- function() test[, ncols - vapply(transpose(.SD), uniqueN, 1L) + 1L]

identical(f2(), f1())
# [1] FALSE

identical(f3(), f1())
# [1] TRUE

identical(f4(), f1())
# [1] TRUE

identical(unname(f5()), f1())
# [1] TRUE


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), times=5L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  f1() 1883.7817 1903.7626 1940.5378 1922.6539 1981.1139 2011.3771     5
#  f2() 1821.0437 1901.1188 1933.8926 1908.4297 1999.6216 2039.2491     5
#  f3()  657.4502  666.6721  679.5539  672.6617  686.4095  714.5760     5
#  f4()  167.8048  168.5211  174.3660  169.9920  180.1304  185.3816     5
#  f5()  146.0255  154.6341  159.4630  160.1968  164.3369  172.1219     5
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and thanks for the hint. Hmm if possible I would like to avoid melt/keep the original dt-structure, because it takes forever on a big datatable to make this transformation

Comment: @User878239 Arguably you should have the data in melted form and discard the wide form. Fwiw, there's something like `test[, d := vapply(transpose(.SD), anyDuplicated, 1L) > 0, .SDcols=c("a","b","c")]`, but I wouldn't expect it to be efficient nor to extend to whatever your next rowwise operation is.

Comment: @Frank this is nice, but it doesnt count the duplicates. The result is a boolean.

Comment: @User878239 added one without `melt`

Comment: Yeah, I had misread the question @User8 sorry. A different function instead of anyDuplicated is needed, adapting chinsoon's: `DT[, d := .N - vapply(transpose(.SD), uniqueN, 1L), .SDcols=c("a","b","c")]`

Comment: Thanks the datatable sol works. Now I don't know who was fastest with a working datatable sol, so I accepted this one, because it has the highest upvotes. I will upvote all of the replies as soon as I can, however, as they all seem to work. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you don't have that last column then you can get your desired result (modulo your clarifying comment) with :

```
test[ ,duplicatercds := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) {sum(table(x))-length(table(x))}), 
                          by=1:nrow(test) ]
> test
   a b c duplicatercds
1: 1 1 5             1
2: 2 4 6             0
3: 3 6 9             0
```

And a 'test' with a more complex example:

```
> test <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,6),c=c(5,6,9), d=c(1,2,3), c=c(5,6,9))
> test
   a b c d c
1: 1 1 5 1 5
2: 2 4 6 2 6
3: 3 6 9 3 9
> test[ , duplicatercds := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) {sum(table(x))-length(table(x))}), by=1:nrow(test) ]
> test
   a b c d c duplicatercds
1: 1 1 5 1 5             3
2: 2 4 6 2 6             2
3: 3 6 9 3 9             2
```

Or maybe:

```
test[ , duplicatercds := apply(.SD, 1,
                                    function(x) {sum(table(x))-length(table(x))}) ]
```

Comment: Right you are. I see no difference

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `diff` as part of `apply` function.

```
test <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,4,6),c=c(5,6,9))
test$dup <- apply(test,1,function(x)sum(diff(sort(x))==0))
test
#    a b c dup
# 1: 1 1 5   1
# 2: 2 4 6   0
# 3: 3 6 9   0
```

Comment: @User878239 If solution worked for you then you can accept answer by clicking on `tick` symbol in left of the answer box.

Comment: hmm your solution does not work if I have duplicate zeros, e.g. in `test <- data.table(a=c(0,2,3),b=c(0,4,6),c=c(5,6,9))`

Comment: @User878239 Did you use `order` part?

Comment: yes I copied your code from above, only changing the datatable to include some zeros. In that case, duplicate zeros are not counted

Comment: I think I had missed vector selection part while applying `order`. Have a look at again.

Comment: just use `test[, dupercds := MKR's_code]` to convert into data.table syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can do a table, and count how many have a frequency of more than 1

```
test=test[,1:3]#Remove your duplicatercds
test[, duplicatercds:=sum(table(unlist(.SD))>1),by=.(1:nrow(test))][]

   a b c duplicatercds 
1: 1 1 5             1           
2: 2 4 6             0          
3: 3 6 9             0
```

Comment: interesting solution, but why doesn't it work for more columns? e.g. it throws an error if you dont remove the previous duplicaterecords

Comment: It thouws an error because you are trying to have two columns with the same name.. Change the name and it will work